# static variables can not be accessed by other class

Tags: java, android

```
public static DevicePolicyManager minochaDevicePolicyManager;
public static ComponentName minochaDevicePolicyAdmin;
```

the above code is in my `MainActivity java` class above the `onCreate`.
Since it is static shouldn't it be accessed by other classes? i have this class `MyBroadCastReceiver`(code below)

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String LOG_TAG="DevicePolicyAdmin";
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Service Started");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int  minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1990, 1, 1, hour, minute);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    String str=date.charAt(0)+""+date.charAt(1)+""+date.charAt(3)+""+date.charAt(4);
    minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str,0);
}
}
```

The `minochaDevicePolicyManager` can not be resolved in the BroadcastReceiver class. Why? it is a static variable so it should be able to be accessed by other classes right?

Comment: Static Rule - static can be accessed by or from static class/block/variable only.

Comment: Also static variables need to be accessed by their Class name. For eg: `MainActivity.minochaDevicePolicyManager`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access a static field from a second class you need to `import static` the field, or access by the class name.

```
 minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str,0);
```

should be something like

```
 MainActivity.minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str,0);
```

Answer (score 4):

`static` variables are attached to the class not it's object, which means it can be called directly from the Class name without creating an object.

You are trying to access the variable like a local variable.

Change

```
minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str,0);
```

to

```
MainActivity.minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str,0);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should access it like so:

```
MainActivity.minochaDevicePolicyManager
```

Answer (score 0):

Static Variables are Class Variables.If you are calling a static variable from the same class then you can call only with the class name but when you are calling a static method from other class you should use Class Name dot method name i.e

```
CLASS.method()
```